TipTip Tooltip Not Working on Multi-Select Element
I am using the TipTip JavaScript plugin to display tooltips on form inputs, including multi-select elements. The tooltips work fine on other input elements but are not showing up on the multi-select input. Below is the relevant code snippet I am using:
$(function () {
    // Tooltip
    $(".form_tiptip").tipTip({
        maxWidth: "auto",
        defaultPosition: "bottom",
        delay: 0,
        activation: "focus"
    });
});

<tr class="input-row">
    <td class="input-label"><?php echo __(T_FACILITY_NAME); ?></td>
    <td class="input-required"><span class="require-label"><?php echo __("*"); ?></span></td>
    <td class="input-form">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input(
            'store_id',
            [
                'id' => 'store-select',
                'type' => 'select',
                'empty' => '-',
                'options' => array_map(fn($x) => ['value' => $x['id'], 'text' => $x['store_name']], $shoppingStores),
                'default' => isset($selectedStore) ? $selectedStore['store_id'] : null,
                'disabled' => isset($selectedStore),
                'label' => false,
                'title' => CHK_STORE_NAME,
                'class' => 'input-xlarge chkselect form_tiptip multi-select'
            ]
        ); ?>
    </td>

What I Have Tried:

Verified that the .form_tiptip class is applied to the multi-select
element.
Checked that the title attribute is present on the multi-select
element.
Confirmed that the TipTip plugin works for other input types in the
same form.
Issue:
Despite the above efforts, the tooltip does not appear when focusing
on the multi-select element. The same setup works fine with text
inputs and other elements.

Question:

How can I make TipTip work with multi-select elements? Is there any
workaround or additional configuration required for TipTip to support
multi-select elements?

